# Is is possible to get union of arrays in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to do union calculation of arrays in Elasticsearch. I have googled a lot but still got no clue or even not sure if it is really possible.

I have these documents:

```
PUT test_agg_array/_doc/1
{
  "key": "hoge",
  "value": [1, 2]
}

PUT test_agg_array/_doc/2
{
  "key": "hoge",
  "value": [2, 3]
}
```

What I want to get:

```
{
  "key: "hoge",
  "union_values": [1, 2, 3]
}
```

I think the query look like below but no success yet

```
GET test_agg_array/_search
{
  "query": {...},
  "aggs": {
    "aggByKey": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "key"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "aggValue": {
          "**union**": {
            "field": "value"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36765775/elasticsearch-combine-fields-from-multiple-documents

Comment: Thank you for the comment. The "combine" operation is exactly what I want to do. I'll close this post and try that solution